# Get the clientID of nested panel control in masterpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, master-pages, clientid

This is the control structure

ContentPlaceHolder 
  --> Wizard 
      --> Panel

I am using setTimeout to display the panel after x minutes.

How do I get the ClientID of the panel?

The line of javascript needed is something like:

```
setTimeout(displayExtendSession('<%= ExtendSession.ClientID  %>', 600000);
```

aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ...>
    <asp:Wizard ID="wizard1" runat="server" ... >
        <asp:Panel ID="ExtendSession" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="ExtendSessionLifePrompt" runat="server" Text="Your session is going to expire in 1 minute. Would you like to extend your Session?"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="ExtendSessionLife" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
            <input type="button" id="CancelExtendSessionLife" value="No" onclick="HideExtendSession('<%= ExtendSession.ClientID %>'); return false;" />  
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Wizard>
</asp:Content>
```

javascript

```
function HideExtendSession(msgBox) {
    if (msgBox)
        document.getElementById(msgBox).style.display = "none";
}
function DisplayExtendSession(msgBox) {
    if (msgBox) 
        document.getElementById(msgBox).style.display = "block";
}

setTimeout(DisplayExtendSession('<%= ExtendSession.ClientID  %>', 600000);
setTimeout(HideExtendSession('<%= ExtendSession.ClientID %>', 720000);
```

Comment: And what is not working for you with that piece of code?

Comment: what does your markup look like?

Comment: Agree with Oded, I think your problem is with the interval which is 10 minutes that is weird.

Comment: BC30451: Name 'ExtendSession' is not declared.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what the interval is set at. The javascript needs to handle the prompt so there isn't a postback which would extend the session.

Answer (score 1):

To get the client Id of `ExtendSession` I think what you need to do is:

```
setTimeout(displayExtendSession('<%= wizard1.FindControl("ExtendSession").ClientID  %>', 600000);
```

**updated**

if you can't get to wizard1, then maybe this:

```
setTimeout(displayExtendSession('<%= Content1.FindControl("wizard1").FindControl("ExtendSession").ClientID  %>', 600000);
```

I would expect the double quotes to be fine, but I'm sure you can switch them around if that's not helping.

Comment: I get an error stating wizard1 is not declared. Btw, I think you should also use the double quotes outside the expression and single quotes inside.

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

to

```
<asp:Panel ID="ExtendSession" runat="server">
```

resulting in

```
<asp:Panel ID="ExtendSession" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
```

asp.net will not mangle your panel's id and

```
document.getelementbyid("ExtendSession")
```

will return the id of the <div> rendered by the asp:panel control.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not running asp.net 4 so I can't leverage the use of ClientIDMode

Answer (score 0):

If you are not much into performance and all,

Following code might be one way to easily achieve the tasks.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(FindRecursiveControl(this,"ExtendSessionLife").ClientID.ToString());
}

Control FindRecursiveControl(Control cd, string Name)
{
    if (cd.ID == Name && cd.ID !=null)
        return cd;

    foreach (Control c in cd.Controls)
    {
        Control cfind = FindRecursiveControl(c, Name);

        if (cfind != null)
            return cfind;
    }

    return null;
}
```